# Question related to the number of rational curves on a hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials

The following is from a PhD thesis "Algebraic Circle Method" by Thibaut Pugin, which I am currently reading.

Let $k$ be a finite field of order $q$. 
Let $\mathfrak{X} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ be the projective hypersurface
defined by $f = x_0^d + ... + x_n^d$.
Let $\mathcal{M}_r = \mathcal{M}_r(\mathbb{P}^1_k, \mathfrak{X})$ be the space
of degree $r$ rational curves on $\mathfrak{X}$.
We define 
$$
P_r = \{ x \in k[u,v]: \text{homogeneous and of degree } r \}.
$$
If $V$ is a scheme of finite type over a finite field $k$ and $R$ is a 
finite $k$-algebra we denote
$$
[V]_R = \#V(R)/ \#R^{\text{dim }_e V},
$$
where $\text{dim }_e V$ is the "expected dimension" of $V$ (It is not well
defined in the thesis either). But to give an example,
for 
$$
M_r = \{ (x_0, ..., x_n)\in P^{n+1}_r : f(x_0, ..., x_n) = 0\},
$$
the expected dimension is given by $(r+1)(n+1)-(rd+1)$.

I have two questions:
(1) What would be the expected dimension of $[\mathcal{M}_r]$?

(2) On page 28, he shows that 
$$
[M_r] = (1- q^{-1})\sum_{\deg D \leq r} [\mathcal{M}_{r - \deg D}],
$$
where $D$ is an effective divisor. From here, he says "Expanding into an Euler product, we get
$$
[M_r] = (1- q^{-1}) [\mathcal{M}_{r}] \zeta_{\mathbb{P}^1}(q^{d-n})
+ O(q^{r(d - (n+1))}),"
$$ 
for which I am stuck on. Could anyone possibly give me a hint or explanation
so that I can figure this out?

I would greatly appreciate any help understanding this. Thank you very much!